# Textbook Recommendations Covering The Adaptive Immune System

Tags: immunology, book-recommendation

I will soon begin work on a project about immunology. I would like to read more about the main mechanisms of the immune system.

What books or articles could you recommend to me? In particular I am interested in the adaptive immune system.

I would appreciate if some of the recommendations are at an undergraduate level as I do not have a background in biology.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MattDMo 's answer is a great starting point. You probably also want to look through **Nature Reviews: Immunology** to get an overview of what is  currently occurring in the field today. From there, you can look at the referenced articles in more specialized journals for topics related to your project.

Comment: echoing @AMR 's sentiment, **Annual Reviews of Immunology** is also a great resource if you're looking to go deeper than textbook-level, although **Nature Reviews** in general has better pictures :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two books that I see as "standards" in the field:

- [*Cellular and Molecular Immunology, 8th Ed.*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0323222757) by Abbas et al.
- [*Immunobiology*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0815342438) previously by Charlie Janeway, who unfortunately has passed, so it is now authored by Kenneth Murphy. Many people just refer to it as "Janeway".

These texts can be used both at an undergraduate and graduate level (I used them in both), and are updated every few years. The latest edition of *Immunobiology* is from 2011, while *CMI* is from 2014, so you may want to start with that one first.

An [earlier version of *Immunobiology*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10757/) is also available for free on NCBI's Bookshelf, but unfortunately you can't read directly through it, you'll need to search for what you're interested in.

Comment: +1 for *Cellular and Molecular Immunology*. My undergrad immuno course used Parham's *The Immune System* and I really didn't like it. There are very good figures in Abbas' text, and I think it's also more in-depth for those of us who want to know more without multiple textbooks.

Comment: The Immunobiology book (previously by Janeway) - is awesome! Used it for my graduate school course on immunology. Great pictures and explanations - even for someone who didn't have a strong background in immunology. I would recommend that to anyone interested in learning more about immunology.